# Cart count badge in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a cart count in my toolbar.
I have a main activity and a few fragments.

The code to increment the cart count is as follows.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem getItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_addcart);
    if (getItem != null) {
        cartCounterActionView = (CartCounterActionView) getItem.getActionView();
        cartCounterActionView.setCount(new Database(this).getCountCart(Common.currentUser.getPhone()));
        //Set a ClickListener, the text,
        //the background color or something like that
        cartCounterActionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.frame, new Cart());
                tx.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code works fine in my main activity but what I want to do is , to call this cart count in my fragments so that I can set the count in the fragments too.I want to call it in another method beside oncreateoption.Any help pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Menu` member variable and assign it in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
private Menu myMenu;
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    myMenu = menu;
    // now you can use myMenu to fetch your MenuItem outside onCreateOptionsMenu
    ...
}
```

Or, if all you want is for the code inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be run from your fragment, you can call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`.